# How can I create a pandas dataframe column for each part-of-speech tag?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, pos-tagger

I have a dataset that consists of tokenized, POS-tagged phrases as one column of a dataframe:

[Current Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TvQU.png)

I want to create a new column in the dataframe, consisting only of the proper nouns in the previous column:

[Desired Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chhmw.png)

Right now, I'm trying something like this for a single row:

```
if 'NNP' in df['Description_POS'][96][0:-1]:
df['Proper Noun'] = df['Description_POS'][96]
```

But then I don't know how to loop this for each row, and how to obtain the tuple which contains the proper noun. 
I'm very new right now and at a loss for what to use, so any help would be really appreciated!

Edit: I tried the solution recommended, and it seems to work, but there is an issue.

this was my dataframe: 
[Original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPZD.png)

After implementing the code recommended

```
df['Proper Nouns'] = df['POS_Description'].apply(
    lambda row: [i[0] for i in row if i[1] == 'NNP'])
```

it looks like this: 
[Dataframe after creating a proper nouns column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z5wb.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the apply method, which as the name suggests will apply the given function to every row of the dataframe or series. This will return a series, which you can add as a new column to your dataframe

```
df['Proper Nouns'] = df['POS_Description'].apply(
    lambda row: [i[0] for i in row if i[1] == 'NNP'])
```

I am assuming the POS_Description dtype to be a list of tuples.

Comment: Hey, I think your answer worked, but I'm now getting characters like "â€¢, â€¢, â€¢, â€¢, â€¢" in the proper nouns columns. Would you know what's going wrong?

Comment: Need more details. Share the result of df.head() before and after.

Comment: Hi, I added df.head() screenshots.

Comment: This seems to be some encoding issue. If you are reading from a file, give the parameter encoding='utf-8' and then try. I have not seen such issue before, so can't comment more on this.